# Is it possible to read passport`s data from nfc chip in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, nfc

I'm working on the app where I need to read passport's data form nfc chip, but I can't find some packages or information about solution. I know about nfc_manager and flutter_nfc_kit but both of them don't allow to read passport data. Also I know that this info cannot be readed in simple way, cause it have a some security stuff.

Anybody know how to solve my issue?

Comment: Hello, im interested in your app and would like to talk to you in private. Do you have a telegram/whatsapp/email you can share with me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, there is a library based on the `flutter_nfc_kit` to read the passport. Please refer to [dmrtd](https://github.com/ZeroPass/dmrtd).

Comment: Thanks, I have already used it. But maybe you know some tools for convert image from dg2 file (bytes, hex) to jpeg?

Comment: https://github.com/AndyQ/NFCPassportReader and https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD might be possible app or library to decode the DG2 file.

Comment: how did you fetch the data from the passport using this library ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [ZeroPass
/
dmrtd](https://github.com/ZeroPass/dmrtd)

They r importing dg2 image support to it you can check development branch on it

It's example app can reading passport or id card, after doing implementation to your app you need to set another thigs to make it work

1: in bottom of your PodFile set camera like this,

```
post_install do |installer|
 installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
  flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  target.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
     '$(inherited)',
     'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
   ]
  end
 end
end
```

2: You need to add Runner.entitlements file into Runner, it's not generated by itself i had to take it from package's example app.

bonus: packages nfc app needs to some data from card for scann cards chip, by default example app wants it from text editing controller and date picker but if you use flutter_mrz_scanner and take that data from camera then scan card with nfc later, thats more easy to use.

Comment: is it possible to read the photo of the id with same way ?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you can find it packages development branch, you need to implement it by your self

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit late but you can take a look at [Securepass](https://github.com/rammah778/Securepass) which is flutter app integrated with an android module that uses [JMRTD](https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD) library.